# Make the grid of chart control to begin at an even hour

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I am using a chart control which in x axis displays time, initialized as follows:

```
        With Chart1.ChartAreas(0)
            .AxisX.Minimum = 0
            .AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm"
            .AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours
            .AxisX.Interval = 2

            .AxisY.Minimum = 0
        End With
        Chart1.Series(0).IsXValueIndexed = True
```

Sometimes the data points start at an odd hour like the picture bellow
[image]

My question is how can I make the grid and labels begin at an even hour instead.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got it. I just removed the commands
.AxisX.Minimum = 0 in With...End With statement and
Chart1.Series(0).IsXValueIndexed = True
and now the grid always begins at an even hour automatically.